# NullPointer exception when switching from one class to another using Intent on android phone

Tags: android

My application works perfectly on emulator without any errors but when I run it on android real device/phone  then it stops unexpectedly! The logcat errors are: `java.lang.NullPointerException`. The code at which this application fails ,or in other words the code at which it runs correct on emulator but not working on real phone is:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookActivity.this, GoogleMapActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

I just cant understand the problem please help.please help.

Comment: Can you post the Logcat.. may be will find any more...??

Comment: its not coming on emulator so sorry... i had seen the logcat error on device so i cant post it...

Comment: Without some code or logcat, i am afraid we cant help you Kailash. There can be numerous reasons for this exception. We cant keep playing trial and error out here.

Comment: connect your phone to eclipse. Run the code and get the logcat error report.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<activity android:name=.AnotherActivity />` to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: hey if we dont write this statement then emulator show runtime exception but it doesnt..

Comment: and it runs on emulator that means.. obviously i had added this things

Comment: i cant coz it error comes up on phone.. i somehow managed to find out that it is NullPointerWception